# compile python code to PyCodeObject and marshal to pyc file

Tags: python, compilation, marshalling

I try to compile python code to PyCodeObject and marshal to pyc file.
But when I import my pyc file, it fails and the traceback is "ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)"
Here is my code

```
import struct
import marshal
import time
import imp 
import sys 

def dump(co, filename):
    magic = imp.get_magic()
    time_string = struct.pack('L', int(time.time()))
    f = open("merge.pyc", "wb")
    f.write(magic)
    f.write(time_string)
    marshal.dump(dco, f)
    f.close()

demo = open("demo.py").read()
dco = compile(demo, "demo.py", "exec")
dump(dco, "dco.pyc")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `ValueError` raised is because of the mismatched type of timestamp. You should make sure the `fmt` parameter (`L` used, which standard size is 4 bytes) in `struct.pack` has the same length with your python executable.

<strike>Since the value of timestamp do not effect on the final result, making the type suitable is enough here. Try to use `Q` instead of `L` to ensure 8 bytes if you are using 64bit version of CPython.</strike>

=== UPDATED BEGIN ===

Sorry, I made a serious mistake in the previous description.

`L` without any prefix, means [native](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment), and the size and byte order is the same to the machine’s native format and byte order (In 64bit CPython, it would be 8 bytes). However the timestamp written to `pyc` file is always be 4 bytes (little endian) in both Python 2 and 3.

If the used is Python2, we should use `<L` instead of `L`, which has standard size, 4 bytes.

If the used is Python3, in additional to `timestamp`, we should add another 4 bytes field, `source size`, as the following code shown (*importlib/_bootstrap_external.py, Python3.6.4*)

```
def _code_to_bytecode(code, mtime=0, source_size=0):
    """Compile a code object into bytecode for writing out to a byte-compiled
    file."""
    data = bytearray(MAGIC_NUMBER)
    data.extend(_w_long(mtime))
    data.extend(_w_long(source_size))
    data.extend(marshal.dumps(code))
    return data
```

At last, you could refer to `pkgutil.read_code()`, which is the reverse order of writing code.

=== UPDATED END ===

By the way, there are some defects in your code: Have not use the `co` and `filename` parameters in `dump` function

Comment: In face, I just findout the problem one minute before. I use 64 bit python so I can change the "L" to "I" to ensure the byte of this part is 4. Any way thank you !

Comment: By the way, which version of Python you used, 2 or 3?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that why  the result of struct.calcsize('L') is 8  while struct.calcsize('<L') is 4 in 64 bit python. Would you help me?

Comment: I use 64 bit python 2.7.13

Comment: According to the document of `struct` https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment, `L` without any prefix, means native, which the size depends on the host system used, could either be 4 or 8. But `>L` and `<L` are different, their size are the standard size, 4 bytes.